# A better way to restore segued iOS UIViewControllers

Tags: segue, state-restoration

I have a UITableViewController which displays a list of options. Tapping each option navigates to another view controller using a segue

The following code is needed to restore the app's state. But is there a cleaner way? I've included code to handle two options in the list but image 10 options!

```
class SettingsViewController:UITableViewController {

var isRestoration = false
var aboutVC:AboutViewController?
var feedbackVC:FeedbackViewController?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if isRestoration {
        isRestoration = false
        restoreChildIfPresent()
    } else {
        // nullify so when child is closed, we don't reopen
        // on next restoration
        forgetChildren()
    }
}

override func restoreChildIfPresent() {
    if let aboutVC = aboutVC {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutVC, animated:false)
    } else if let feedbackVC = feedbackVC {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(feedbackVC, animated:false)
    }
}

func forgetChildren() {
    aboutVC = nil
    charterVC = nil
    feedbackVC = nil
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
    aboutVC = nil
    feedbackVC = nil
    if segue.identifier == "aboutSegue" {
        aboutVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AboutViewController    
    } else if segue.identifier == "feedbackSegue" {
        feedbackVC = segue.destinationViewController as? FeedbackViewController
    }
}

    override func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder:NSCoder) {
    isRestoration = true
    aboutVC = coder.decodeObjectForKey("aboutVC") as? AboutUsViewController
    feedbackVC = coder.decodeObjectForKey("feedbackVC") as? FeedbackViewController
    super.decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}

override func encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder:NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(aboutVC, forKey:"aboutVC")
    coder.encodeObject(feedbackVC, forKey:"feedbackVC")
    super.encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```

I'm surprised I need to encodeObject() the child VCs as they are not embedded (for those embedded in UITabbarController one does need to encodeObject() children).

My main 'dislike' are `restoreChildIfPresent()` which will grow with the addition of more ViewControllers and the ugly need for `forgetChildren()`

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced the code in my question, by using a single reference to a UIViewController, to something more manageable. But the structure is the same. Further Swifty-ness can be added but I'm more interested in an alternative approach, or confirmation that this approach is the recommended practice.

```
class SettingsViewController:UITableViewController {

var isRestoration = false
var childVC:UIViewController?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if isRestoration {
        isRestoration = false
        restoreChildIfPresent()
    } else {
        // nullify so when child is closed, we don't reopen
        // on next restoration
        forgetChild()
    }
}

override func restoreChildIfPresent() {
    if let childVC = childVC {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(childVC, animated:false)
    }
}

func forgetChild() {
    childVC = nil
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
    childVC = nil
    if segue.identifier == "aboutSegue" {
        childVC = segue.destinationViewController    
    } else if segue.identifier == "feedbackSegue" {
        childVC = segue.destinationViewController
    }
}

override func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder:NSCoder) {
    isRestoration = true
    childVC = coder.decodeObjectForKey("childVC")
    super.decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}

override func encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder:NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(childVC, forKey:"childVC")
    super.encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```